# concatenation string with links missing slashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
console.log(mylink)
```

with above console, `mylink` result is like normal, like http://example.com/something.jpg.

I concatenated it like this

```
var html = '<div id="head" style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)),url("'+ mylink+'") no-repeat;">';
```

but the result is broken, in my DOM I see the slashes is gone.

Comment: The issue isn't the slashes - it's because the syntax of your CSS `background` property is wrong.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan are you kidding me?

Comment: No, why would you think that?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan because when I hard coded some links it work..

Comment: can you tell me what is the purpose? are you trying to Open URL inside a div tag ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV set the link to the background img

Answer (score 2):

Escape quotes like`\'`

Use

```
var html = '<div id="head" style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)),url(\'"'+ mylink+'\') no-repeat;">';
```

Comment: @Fernandez try with `\'`